Expo drawer component not showing up on certain iPhones in production, but functional and showing up on local simulator
We’re working with react expo using expo file router and typescript, we’re on expo sdk 51 configured with react native 0.75. We’re trying to implement a drawer navigator using drawer component from expo-router/drawer. We’re running a development build locally on a simulator using expo go and a physical device and the drawer navigator renders and works well, but when we build the production profile using EAS build, the drawer header icon (Hamburger icon) disappears but the functionality is still there (Only disappeared visually). This issue occurs only on iPhones, except for the iPhone 11 (Android is working). We are running  node 20.15.0. We’ve tried it with the minimum reproducible example without installing anything other than the default expo router installation and it still does not show up on those devices.
TLDR: We tried implementing a simple hamburger nav bar, and it worked on android and an iPhone 11 in production, but we found the icon didn't show up on any other iPhones we tested (X, 12, 15 pro) despite it rendering well on a local simulator. We tried setting a fallback icon in its place but still no visual displayed, despite it being functional when the area was clicked.
How it should show up
How it is showing up on most iPhones (Hamburger nav bar in the top left missing)
You can find the repository here: https://github.com/AntonioRoye/drawer-header-test
Our minimal reproducible code:
//package.json
{
  "name": "stickersmash",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

//eas.json
{
    "cli": {
      "version": ">= 10.2.3",
      "appVersionSource": "remote"
    },
    "build": {
      "development": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal",
        "channel": "development"
      },
      "ios-simulator": {
        "extends": "development",
        "ios": {
          "simulator": true
        }
      },
      "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "channel": "preview"
      },
      "production": {
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "channel": "production"
      }
    },
    "submit": {
      "production": {
        "android": {
          "serviceAccountKeyPath": "****",
          "track": "internal",
          "releaseStatus": "draft"
        },
        "ios": {
          "appleId":  "****",
          "ascAppId":  "****",
          "appleTeamId": "****",
          "bundleIdentifier":  "****"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  

// VehiclePage.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

const VehiclePage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>("Vehicle Info");
  const [vehicleType, setVehicleType] = useState<string>("Passenger Vehicle");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Vehicle Page</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}>
        {/* Tab Buttons */}
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
              styles.tabButton,
              activeTab === "Vehicle Info" && styles.activeTabButton,
            ]}
            onPress={() => setActiveTab("Vehicle Info")}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.tabButtonText,
                activeTab === "Vehicle Info" && styles.activeTabButtonText,
              ]}
            >
              Vehicle Info
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
              styles.tabButton,
              activeTab === "Odometer" && styles.activeTabButton,
            ]}
            onPress={() => setActiveTab("Odometer")}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.tabButtonText,
                activeTab === "Odometer" && styles.activeTabButtonText,
              ]}
            >
              Odometer
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/* Content based on tab selection */}
        {activeTab === "Vehicle Info" ? (
          <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Vehicle Type</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={vehicleType}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => setVehicleType(itemValue)}
                style={styles.picker}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="Select Vehicle" value="" />
                <Picker.Item label="Motor Vehicle" value="Motor Vehicle" />
                <Picker.Item label="Passenger Vehicle" value="Passenger Vehicle" />
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Odometer Tab Content</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#0078A0",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  tabButton: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  activeTabButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#0078A0",
  },
  tabButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#000",
  },
  activeTabButtonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  contentContainer: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  pickerContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: "#ddd",
    padding: 5,
  },
  picker: {
    width: "100%",
  },
});

export default VehiclePage;

//index.tsx
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>Edit app/index.tsx to edit this screen.</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

//_layout.tsx
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {Drawer} from "expo-router/drawer";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";



export default function App() {
  return (
 
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Drawer
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: true,
              drawerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#404040",
              },
              drawerLabelStyle: {
                color: "white"
              },
            }}
          >
            <Drawer.Screen
              name="index"
              options={{
                drawerLabel: "Index",
                headerTitle: () => null,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                }
              }}
            />
            
            <Drawer.Screen
              name="vehicle"
              options={{
                drawerLabel: "Vehicle",
                title: "Vehicle",
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                },
              }}
            />
           
          </Drawer>
       </GestureHandlerRootView>
  
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawerHeader: {
    height: 150,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  drawerIcon: {
    width: 250,
    height: 67,
  },

  loadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
  },
});

